# The server uses a certificate signed by an unknown authority

Tags: openshift

Any help or hint would be greatly appreciated it!!
I have windows 11 Pro.
I installed openshift.

I did "crc setup" and I did "crc start":
INFO Adding crc-admin and crc-developer contexts to kubeconfig...
ERRO Cannot update kubeconfig: x509: certificate has expired or is not yet valid: current time 2022-05-24T00:01:26-04:00 is after 2022-01-13T22:29:55Z
Started the OpenShift cluster.

The server is accessible via web console at:
https://console-openshift-console.apps-crc.testing

I get the following error when I tried to login:

C:\Users\Albert Lam>oc login -u developer https://api.crc.testing:6443
The server uses a certificate signed by an unknown authority.
You can bypass the certificate check, but any data you send to the server could be intercepted by others.
Use insecure connections? (y/n): n

error: The server uses a certificate signed by unknown authority. You may need to use the --certificate-authority flag to provide the path to a certificate file for the certificate authority, or --insecure-skip-tls-verify to bypass the certificate check and use insecure connections.

C:\Users\Albert Lam>oc login -u developer https://api.crc.testing:6443
The server uses a certificate signed by an unknown authority.
You can bypass the certificate check, but any data you send to the server could be intercepted by others.
Use insecure connections? (y/n): y

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it was caused by an old certificate that was expired and had nothing to do (VMware one) with Openshift.

I've found the problem by viewing the certificate inside my chrome browser after navigating to https://console-openshift-console.apps-crc.testing.

The correct certificate should have ***.apps-crc.testing** as CN, but mine has another one.

I suggest you to find the wrong certificate and delete it if expired.

On windows, for VMware you can find it inside C:\ProgramData\VMware\SSL.

On Windows you can look for certificates by using the "manage certificates" app.